# Replace letter 'S' with '5'

Tags: java, methods

I am just learning java and have been given a quick practice lab to do. I have learned only a little about methods and my question has to do with that mostly.

My problem is having to replace all occurrences of the letter s with the number 5. This I can do easily and have no problem doing. However, we have to make a separate method to do the operation.

The code we have to work with is this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchLetter {
    public SwitchLetter()
    {

    }

    public String switchOut(String inputString)
    {

    }
}
```

My question is why is there 2 methods? (SwitchLetter and switch0out)

Also, why is there no main function? My guess for that is that there is a separate main for testing however, that does not solve the 2 functions problem.

Comment: First is related to identify letter and second ins related to change it

Comment: No main method because only one file in a package tends to need a main method. So you will create another file with that utilizes the class that you’ve created here. You’ll essentially have two class files in the package. In java, you want each class to only really do one job

Comment: The first "method" is not a method, it's a [**constructor**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) (same name as class and no return type). Since it is a no-arg constructor, and it doesn't do anything, it doesn't really need to be there, since the default constructor would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't two methods in the first place, **Look Carefully, the first one is a Zero Parameterized constructor because it has no return type**

- the "switchOut" function would receive the call from main() do needed operations, constructors just initialize the variables with something
- Main() method is not mandatory for a class to have. You can call this method by using an object in a main() which is present in another class

Any reference to constructors ( have a reference ) :

https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-constructor-tutorial

Comment: Main is not required ever, in a class or package. At least not by Java itself.

Comment: I wanted to write "suggested", i removed that line however